# Cannot find -lgcc -lc

Tags: cross-compilation, arm, freertos

I'm trying to compile the FreeRTOS port to Raspberry Pi, but when I compile, I get the error:

```
arm-none-eabi-ld: cannot find -lgcc
arm-none-eabi-ld: cannot find -lc
make: *** [kernel.elf] Error 1
```

I'm not sure why this is so. I'm very new to crosscompiling, so I'm suessing I've not set a flag somewhere. I've downloaded the GNU toolchain for ARM from https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded and extracted it into my /usr/local directory and updated the path variable too. If i run a 'arm-none-eabi-gcc --version', I get the correct output:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 4.7.4 20140401      
(release) [ARM/embedded-4_7-branch revision 209195]
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

The makefile for the project specifies two lines, which I've modified as follows:

```
kernel.elf: LDFLAGS += -L "/usr/local/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2014q2/bin/" -lgcc
kernel.elf: LDFLAGS += -L "/usr/local/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2014q2/lib/" -lc
```

I'm guessing this is where I need to change to the correct path, but I'm unsure what the correct path is...

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, if that matters...

Any pointers much appreciated.